# How to convert a byte array of zip files to ZipFile with type as ZipFile?

Tags: java, arrays, zip

```
byte[] zipBytes = fileService.get("RINV_242_20220629-150309.ZIP");
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipBytes);
```

I'm not sure if my code will give you a better understanding of my problem. But I want to convert byte array to zipFile, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) without saving it to a file on  a file system. If you want to get it from a `byte[]` without saving, you need to use [`java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), and wrap the `byte[]` in a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Something like:

```java
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes))) {
    // ...
}
```

The thing you lose compared to `ZipFile` is that you can't enumerate the files or request individual files. Instead, you have to iterate over zip entries with `getNextEntry()`.